# php chat taking way to much memory! Jquery, php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, optimization

So I created a chat with jquery php and mysql.. It also uses ajax. So here is the code

The PHP process page:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                         FROM messages 
                     ORDER BY id DESC  
                        LIMIT 30") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($row['correct'] == 1) {
    $correct = "<font color='green'>";
  } else {
    $correct = "<font color='red'>";
  }

  echo $correct;
  echo $row['name']. ": ". $row['message'] . "</font>";
  echo "<br />";
}
```

My jquery on the index page looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form[name=answer]').submit(function() {
    validate();
    return false;
  });

function validate() {
  $.post("http://localhost:8888/school/procees.php", 
          {answer: $('input[name=answer]').val(),
          questionid: $('input[name=questionid]').val(), 
          name: $('input[name=id]').val()}, 'json');
}

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#about').load('maketable.php');
}, 1000);

});
```

I understand that running a check and then printing everything out requires takes a lot of memory I do not know how to do it any other way. Suggestion and criticism of the code is welcome. How can I improve it?

Comment: continual polling and databases aren't a good way to handle this. most like FB use a technique called long polling (aka Comet). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) there will also be support for socket connections when html5 is more widely implimented, which would be the ultimate way to go with this, because nothing would need to be held in a database or other data source. messages would come in and be immediately sent back out to each subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's other code you are using here which might/might not help - what I would say is that if this is live chat consider using the MEMORY table type in mysql - it has very fast reads which makes it a good candidate for this type of application.

Make sure your ajax requests only ask for data that you haven't already loaded - that may help.

If you need more help we'd need to see the maketable.php code too..

Comment: oops I included maketable.php not procees the code you see is make table

Comment: when a mssg is added to the conversation store its time too - when you submit the requst for more chat data include last request time (or null if its page first load) the script can then select only entries that have been submitted since that time and return those. you'll have to store a lastrequesttime and lastrequesttimetmp, before making the request update the tmp value - if the request is successful set lastrequesttime to tmp time - if not leave it alone - that way you won't miss any data out if anything goes bang

Comment: @Ian Wood Where can I find more information about this "MEMORY table type in mysql"?

Comment: I'd probably start with google but to save you a search try this - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html - yes it does have tablelevel locking but its super fast.

Answer (score 3):

[Node](http://nodejs.org/)(js) was made pretty much for this exact scenario of support high concurrency with minimum overhead. Combine it with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and you have HTML5 sockets with fallback for older devices.

Want to see a live example of this running on your system? Just clone [this project](https://github.com/chrismatthieu/CHATS.iO) on github.